# Access Denied for User @localhost, via PHP Search

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Currently creating a Website to deal with purchasing.

I'm trying to create a search function but when I search I get the following error:

Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'x32334732'

I know there is other questions on this, but couldn't find anything conclusive.

My user has all privileges except Shutdown, so that's fine.

My php page calling the search has code as such:

```
    include("header.html");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "X32334732", "X32334732", "X32334732");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Server Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Type = 'Game'");
?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="headGame">Buy Some Games Man</h1>

<form id="searchF" action="Search.php" method="GET">
    <label>Product Search</label>
    <input type="text" name="query">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

And my calling php which seems to have the problem, from my understanding is:

```
    include("header.html");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "X32334732", "X32334732", "X32334732");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Server Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}  
$query = $_GET['query'];

mysql_select_db('X32334732') or die(mysql_error());
```

Lastly as a side query, if I changed my command mysql_select_db("dbName') to mysqli('dbName') it has an error : Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters,....
And after changing it to  mysqli($con, 'dbName') it says no database selected, when i swap the parameters, it says:Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in.
Any help with that would be most appreciated. If not all G though =D

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the problem about your privileges but of your username and password, Database Server Port settings (commonly 3306) and so on. You may check if your Database could be connected to with a client of mysql, such as MySQL Workbench or any others.

Comment: Using XAMPP atm. Also when I connect to mySQL I use the provided name and password IE X32334732 for both. Would this cover what you're suggesting?

Comment: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'x32334732' You wrote this log above. the username is empty there before @ character.

Comment: The page that calls search.php, connects and displays data from that the database. Is there a reason that the same mysql_conenct command might not be working? See above.

Comment: Maybe the reference would help. For mysql_connect, `<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>` But for mysqli_connect, `$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); `